# How can I make xtable work with aggregate(..., FUN = paste)?

Tags: r, latex, aggregate, xtable

Say I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(sector = c(rep('a', 3), rep('b', 4)), id = 1:7)
```

I would like to create a summarized table reporting a list of IDs on each sector, so I do this:

```
table <- xtable(aggregate(id ~ sector, df, paste))
```

However, when I try to use `xtable()` to transform the object above into LaTeX, I get the following error:

```
> xtable(table)
Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

Which is caused by the second column, since `class(table$id)` confirms it is a list.

It should be noted that `xtable()` handles data frames as input well. Changing "paste" to something more common like "sum" or "length" doesn't yield errors.

**What can I do to `table` (or to `xtable`) so it creates the table I want?** The desired  raw output should look something like this:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlr}
  \hline
 & sector & id \\ 
  \hline
1 & a &   1, 2, 3 \\ 
  2 & b &  4, 5, 6, 7\\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a 'collapse' argument to `paste` will succeed:

```
> xtable(aggregate(id ~ sector, df, paste, collapse=","))
% latex table generated in R 3.0.1 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Tue Aug  6 11:46:03 2013
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rll}
  \hline
 & sector & id \\ 
  \hline
1 & a & 1,2,3 \\ 
  2 & b & 4,5,6,7 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: So adding "collapse" turned the second column from list into  a character object. Interesting. That did it (it actually even saved me  step with the real case), thank you!